# Difference between Micrometer Timer.start/stop and Timer.record

Tags: java, grafana, prometheus, micrometer

I wanted to check the latency of database hits(multiple databases) and request processing. What is the better option `Timer.Sample` or `Timer.record`?

I am using Micrometer with Prometheus as base.

Comment: While either can be used in most places, if you provide some code snippets it might help in the suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Timer.record when **you have calculated the duration** taken by the event.

```
default void record(Duration duration)
```

You will typically use Timer.Sample when you want to pass around the Sample to figure out what point to publish the metrics, not necessarily at the exact same place. You also have more fine grained control as to what to publish using the Timer object. 
It is a two step process.

1. Create a Sample **before the event starts** to return an Object of Sample using

   ```
   static Sample start(Clock clock) {..}
   ```
2. Stop the sample and push the metric when the activity is complete using Sample.stop

   ```
   public long stop(Timer timer) {..}
   ```

Eg of that from [TimedAspect](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/aop/TimedAspect.java) -

```
    Timer.Sample sample = Timer.start(registry);
    try {
        return pjp.proceed();
    } finally {
        sample.stop(Timer.builder(timed.value())
                .description(timed.description().isEmpty() ? null : timed.description())
                .tags(timed.extraTags())
                .tags(tagsBasedOnJoinpoint.apply(pjp))
                .publishPercentileHistogram(timed.histogram())
                .publishPercentiles(timed.percentiles().length == 0 ? null : timed.percentiles())
                .register(registry));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is to add option to [manually stop](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_storing_start_state_in_timer_sample) recording

> You may also **store start state in a sample instance that can be stopped later**. The sample records a start time based on the registry’s clock. After starting a sample, execute the code to be timed and finish the operation by calling stop(Timer) on the sample.